# Phonegap 2.2 upgrade: Error calling method on NPObject (Javascript Interface)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am working on a Phonegap app (on Android), and I updated my application with Phonegap 2.2.
Unfortunately, now I get an error while using a Javascript Interface.

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/dossier_med_list.html#/android_asset/www/dossier_med_new.html:22
```

The error occurred when using the Javascript Interface functions:

```
var tel = window.language_classe.getSystemPhoneNumber() ;
```

This is how the class is made:

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class LanguageClass {
    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;
    private Context mContext;


    public LanguageClass( DroidGap gap, WebView view, Context context) {
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
        mContext = context;

    }

    public String getSystemPhoneNumber() {
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tMgr.getLine1Number();
    }

}
```

And this is how I initialize my application:

```
   public class App extends DroidGap
   {
    private LanguageClass language;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        language = new LanguageClass(this, appView, this.getBaseContext());
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(language, "language_classe");

        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/accueil.html", 150000);
    }

}
```

Any clue why this is happening ? I didn't see anything about this issue on the documentation, and I didn't change anything on this functionality while updating to Phonegap 2.2.0.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really have LanguageClass extend the Plugin class from PhoneGap. That way you'll avoid these weird problems.

What I can see in your App class is that you call the LanguageClass() constructor with no parameters but in your LanguageClass class there is no corresponding constructor.

Comment: Ah, that's not related, I'd just tried some stuff before add my question here, and I didn't put my project correctly back on. But thanks for notice that. I edited my post. So, plugin it will be.